# function applyFilters() is not applying the filters on the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, canvas, camanjs

I've been trying to implement the filters (contrast, hue etc) along with the drag and drop functions for a simple online photo editor, I thought the code is correct however the filters are just not applying to the canvas.

If someone could help me and see what I am doing wrong I would be ever so grateful. Many thanks!

Please see the code in this link: [codepen draft](http://codepen.io/h2obubbli/pen/NbbwoB)

```
Caman('#canvasimg', img, function() {
  this.revert(false);
  this.hue(hue).contrast(cntrst).vibrance(vibr).sepia(sep).render();
});
```

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You have an error message which should be a good indicator of the problem. Also, your CodePen has inconsistent indentation. Consistent indentation is very helpful when tracking down bugs.

Comment: Hey Mike, I actually totally forgot about the console, okay I shall check the to see if I can fix the errors and I will clean up the indentations. Many thanks

Comment: Turned out to be the line: Caman('#canvasimg', 'img', function() {
the img needed to be in '' . Thanks again, for some reason the console never occurred to me.